# node.js throwing module-not-found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have been given the task to develop a Room Booking program, using Typescript, as a programming test in connection with a job interview. In doing so i have an Api, which should handle CRUD actions on the underlying database.

Currently however when i run `E:\Code\Work\Application Tests\TV2.Case.Booking\Booking\booking.persistance.api\build> node .\server.js` it throws the error shown below.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../../booking.persistance/src/BookingHandler'
Require stack:
- E:\Code\Work\Application Tests\TV2.Case.Booking\Booking\booking.persistance.api\build\controllers\UserController.js
- E:\Code\Work\Application Tests\TV2.Case.Booking\Booking\booking.persistance.api\build\routes\UserRoute.js
- E:\Code\Work\Application Tests\TV2.Case.Booking\Booking\booking.persistance.api\build\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Code\Work\Application Tests\TV2.Case.Booking\Booking\booking.persistance.api\build\controllers\UserController.js:4:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\Code\\Work\\Application Tests\\TV2.Case.Booking\\Booking\\booking.persistance.api\\build\\controllers\\UserController.js',
    'E:\\Code\\Work\\Application Tests\\TV2.Case.Booking\\Booking\\booking.persistance.api\\build\\routes\\UserRoute.js',
    'E:\\Code\\Work\\Application Tests\\TV2.Case.Booking\\Booking\\booking.persistance.api\\build\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

If i understand the error correctly, it is being thrown by line 4 character 26 (first char of 'require') in UserController.js, shown below.

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.UserController = void 0;
const BookingHandler_1 = require("../../../booking.persistance/src/BookingHandler");
class UserController 
{ 
// REST actions 
}
```

Below is a Hierarchy of the folders/files that are part of my solution. I have omitted alot of files, as otherwise it would be quite big. Each subfolder under Tv2.Case.Booking contains its own tsconfig.json.

```
Tv2.Case.Booking
  | - booking.core
  | - booking.persistance.core
  | - booking.persistance
  |     | - src
  |          | - BookingHandler.ts
  | - booking.persistance.api
        | - build
        |    | - controllers
        |    |    | - UserController.js
        |    | - routes
        |    |    | - UserRoute.js
        |    | - server.js
        | - src
             | - controllers
             |    | - UserController.ts
             | - routes
             |    | - UserRoute.ts
             | - server.ts
```

Moving BookingHandler into booking.persistance.api, simply makes the error thrown on the first import of BookingHandler, that references anything inside booking.presistance. Below the top of BookingHandler.ts can be seen

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Connection, createConnection} from "typeorm";
import { IHandler } from '../../booking.persistance.core/src/IHandler';
import { IEntity } from '../../booking.persistance.core/src/IEntity';
import { IBooking } from '../../booking.core/src/entities/IBooking';
import { IUser } from '../../booking.core/src/entities/IUser';
import { IRoom } from '../../booking.core/src/entities/IRoom';
import { Booking } from "./entity/Booking";
import { User } from "./entity/User";
import { Room } from "./entity/Room";

export class BookingHandler implements IHandler 
{
// CRUD actions using generics.
}
```

Below two pastebin links exist to my tsconfig.json files, which could be relavant in fixing this error.

- booking.persistance.api: https://pastebin.com/Kwatp8iR
- booking.presistance: https://pastebin.com/Yd9vGjy5

I don't have much remaining time left before the interview, and have already used 5+ hours trying to solve it.

In my attempts to fix it, i have tried a number of things, including, but not limited to.

- Renaming BookingHandler
- Moving BookingHandler
- Copying the hierarchy elsewhere and trying to run it there.
- Used absolute paths for references instead of relative paths

Hopefully a solution can be found quickly, or in any case found so others hopefully can solve their error faster.

Edit #1: Fell free to as for any aditional information, that i might be able to supply.

Edit #2: All the code can be found here: https://github.com/andr9528/TV2.Case.Booking

Comment: What command do you use to build the 'api' project? I see the same error. There is no 'src' folder in the 'build' folder and there is no build script in the package.json that is provided to transpile the TS to JS.

Comment: @msenne Inside .vscode there is a tasks.json file (https://github.com/andr9528/TV2.Case.Booking/blob/main/.vscode/tasks.json), which contains tasks performed by Visual Studio Code. My tasks watch for changes in the files and rebuild the projects as well as show me errors. there is no src folder in the build folder, due to how my tsconfig.json is setup ( "rootDir": "./src/").

Comment: The package.json in the api folder lists the entry point to the project as

    "main": "build/src/server.js"

Which doesn't exist. How do you trigger your projects to build?

Comment: @msenne Oh i get what you meant now. booking.persistance.api.package.json included src in the paths to server.js. Having removed the src part, the error is still thrown. Earlier in my debugging session the src folder did exists, and the error still existed then. Thx for pointing that out, sadly it didn't fix it... :(

Comment: I'm not sure how experienced you are with this programming stack, but just to be sure I'll reconfirm some things.
.ts files are not runnable; only .js files are.
TypeScript files have to be transpiled (by 'tsc' the TypeScript compiler) into JavaScript that can then be parsed and run.
If you have lose your /dist/src/ folder then you don't have a compiled version of your application. The project is not configured to work immediately after downloading. If you don't execute those tsc tasks via VSCode there won't be any code to run.

Comment: @msenne I only have 3 days experience with typescript, but have developed using C# since i started my 4 year education, that i finished 1.5 years ago (5.5 years in total ago). Running the server.js as shown in the question, with only the home route, the api runs just fine, as evident by my succeful calls to it with postman.

Going to bed now, as it is almost midnight at me. be back in ~10 hours